# Where is an ideal location to store the root url in an iOS app to get access to an external API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Where is an ideal location to store the root url in an iOS app to get access to an external API?

I'm thinking of using NSBundle but not sure if this is the right. Or should I be using a constant variable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Create a static class that is built to just interact with the API and keep the URL there.
2. You can use a constant variable defined in one of your headers and import it
3. You can use a constant variable defined in Prefix.pch (I don't recommend this)

When I build production grade apps I ALWAYS use the 1st one. It takes a little bit longer, but cleans up code so much more. Let's say that I'm interacting with an API that has my Todo list on a server somewhere. I want to request my first Todo list item where each Todo list item is a Title and Content.

I'll first create a Todo list class that has two properties and one method:

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *content;
    + (MyTodoListItem*)todoListItemFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict;
```

All that one method will do is convert my dictionary that I create in my networking class from a JSON response to a TodoList item.

Now my networking class will have a method definition like:

```
    + (void)getFirstTodoListItemWithCallback:(void(^)(MyTodoListItem *item))callback;
```

And the implementation will have all of this in it:

```
    static NSString * const apiRootURL = @"http://api.foo.com/v1/";
    + (void)getFirstTodoListItemWithCallback:(void(^)(MyTodoListItem *item))callback {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        //where I use the apiRootURL
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", apiRootURL, @"firstTodoListItem"]]];
        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error,%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            } else {
                NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

                //where the magic happens so that I never deal with JSON anywhere else.
                callback([MyTodoListItem todoListItemFromDictionary:dictionary]);
            } 
        }];
    }
```

And finally, to do something with that object:

```
    - (void)getMyFirstObjectSomewhereInSomeViewController {
        [MyTodoListNetworker getFirstTodoListItemWithCallback:(void(^)(MyTodoListItem *item))callback {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@", item.title, item.content);
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it at runtime you can use the settings bundle.  The settings system is a good place to store stuff like this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

If you don't want the user to be able to modify the url, you can add plist for the urls you are using, or just add a key into the Info.plist. Many third-party APIs want keys added to the Info.plist and it's a good place to store immutable though not-sensitive data.  If the url has sensitive information in it, you should never store it in the main bundle in any form.

Comment: If say it was not talking to third party api currently, and I'm just having it talk to by own api. Would I still need to use api keys?

Comment: The keys I'm talking about here are the Keys from the Key/Value pairs in the Info plist.